# Как достать из response текст и распределить его по полям в html?

Tags: php

Через `api Вконтакте` получил ответ следующего содержания в переменую `$result`:

```
{"response":[5238,{"id":10274,"from_id":-31990499,"to_id":-31990499,"date":1519388221,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Весна уже скоро, уже вот-вот, богомолы совсем весенние","media":{"type":"video","owner_id":-31990499,"item_id":456239518},"attachment":{"type":"video","video":{"vid":456239518,"owner_id":-31990499,"title":"Mantodea","duration":23,"description":"","date":1519388141,"views":1305,"image":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcb\/FYsDDyWweqg.jpg","image_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcb\/FYsDDyWweqg.jpg","image_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcd\/bYnm2t9hSas.jpg","access_key":"0f6ede062133ba1514","repeat":1,"first_frame_320":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f453\/-AV8Xc53sTY.jpg","first_frame_160":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f454\/XwcX2BXd_pw.jpg","first_frame_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f455\/4lNgnqrmDvg.jpg","first_frame_800":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f452\/hROmYJS6xpc.jpg"}},"attachments":[{"type":"video","video":{"vid":456239518,"owner_id":-31990499,"title":"Mantodea","duration":23,"description":"","date":1519388141,"views":1305,"image":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcb\/FYsDDyWweqg.jpg","image_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcb\/FYsDDyWweqg.jpg","image_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c834402\/v834402196\/c6bcd\/bYnm2t9hSas.jpg","access_key":"0f6ede062133ba1514","repeat":1,"first_frame_320":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f453\/-AV8Xc53sTY.jpg","first_frame_160":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f454\/XwcX2BXd_pw.jpg","first_frame_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f455\/4lNgnqrmDvg.jpg","first_frame_800":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841430\/v841430196\/6f452\/hROmYJS6xpc.jpg"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":1,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":35,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":6,"user_reposted":0},"online":0,"reply_count":1},{"id":10272,"from_id":-31990499,"to_id":-31990499,"date":1519372682,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Сегодня, кстати, не только День защитника Отечества.

192 года назад Николай Лобачевский прочитал доклад «Сжатое изложение начал геометрии со строгим доказательством теоремы о параллельных», с которого началась неевклидова геометрия. 
Ура Николаю Ивановичу!","attachment":{"type":"doc","doc":{"did":460572241,"owner_id":2904975,"title":"23-feb.gif","size":3057788,"ext":"gif","url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/doc2904975_460572241?hash=89e4abd83437bcde3b&dl=GE4DMOJQGU3TQOA:1519568028:ec8c66e32dbc368c3f&api=1&no_preview=1","date":1519372637,"thumb":"https:\/\/sun9-1.userapi.com\/c834603\/u2904975\/d2\/-3\/m_5a7bd8ce7c.jpg","thumb_s":"https:\/\/sun9-1.userapi.com\/c834603\/u2904975\/d2\/-3\/s_5a7bd8ce7c.jpg","access_key":"dec958ae052e6e5d6a"}},"attachments":[{"type":"doc","doc":{"did":460572241,"owner_id":2904975,"title":"23-feb.gif","size":3057788,"ext":"gif","url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/doc2904975_460572241?hash=89e4abd83437bcde3b&dl=GE4DMOJQGU3TQOA:1519568028:ec8c66e32dbc368c3f&api=1&no_preview=1","date":1519372637,"thumb":"https:\/\/sun9-1.userapi.com\/c834603\/u2904975\/d2\/-3\/m_5a7bd8ce7c.jpg","thumb_s":"https:\/\/sun9-1.userapi.com\/c834603\/u2904975\/d2\/-3\/s_5a7bd8ce7c.jpg","access_key":"dec958ae052e6e5d6a"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":3,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":11,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":3,"user_reposted":0},"online":0,"reply_count":3},{"id":10270,"from_id":-31990499,"to_id":-31990499,"date":1519315493,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Это новый квадрокоптер с тринадцатью камерами, который не потеряется и ни во что не врежется. 

Подробнее: http:\/\/short.nplus1.ru\/pskydio #новостинаукиитехники","media":{"type":"photo","owner_id":-31990499,"item_id":456244743,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc0f\/k9fvP_hSjfM.jpg"},"attachment":{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":456244743,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-31990499,"user_id":100,"src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc0f\/k9fvP_hSjfM.jpg","src_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc10\/qNvls9L4Eqc.jpg","src_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc0e\/g2dZez5l6Tw.jpg","src_xbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc11\/bmGaR6blrCw.jpg","width":620,"height":444,"text":"","created":1519315493,"post_id":10270,"access_key":"8f928a44693ef973b8"}},"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":456244743,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-31990499,"user_id":100,"src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc0f\/k9fvP_hSjfM.jpg","src_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc10\/qNvls9L4Eqc.jpg","src_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc0e\/g2dZez5l6Tw.jpg","src_xbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841324\/v841324403\/6fc11\/bmGaR6blrCw.jpg","width":620,"height":444,"text":"","created":1519315493,"post_id":10270,"access_key":"8f928a44693ef973b8"}}],"post_source":{"type":"api","platform":"iphone"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":12,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":0},"online":0,"reply_count":0},{"id":10269,"from_id":-31990499,"to_id":-31990499,"date":1519305391,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Ребята из [club78469069|СКВТ] сделали журнал: тут вам и будущее исторического здания Политеха, и интервью с лидером СБПЧ Кириллом Ивановым, и о буллинге, и о здоровом образе жизни. 

В общем, целый вечер интересного чтения: https:\/\/polymus.ru\/media\/_media\/files\/1519297429.59\/skvt.pdf #сквт","media":{"type":"photo","owner_id":-31990499,"item_id":456244742,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cd\/5u7GJg_M51Y.jpg"},"attachment":{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":456244742,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-31990499,"user_id":100,"src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cd\/5u7GJg_M51Y.jpg","src_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724ce\/lGtECitdDGc.jpg","src_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cc\/HkFk28TLSWI.jpg","src_xbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cf\/sLfK2j4eZ58.jpg","src_xxbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724d0\/dG8Xb7SunJ4.jpg","src_xxxbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724d1\/JqDRas9jJ-A.jpg","width":2560,"height":1965,"text":"","created":1519305391,"post_id":10269,"access_key":"fbe37a55914e80afa1"}},"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":456244742,"aid":-7,"owner_id":-31990499,"user_id":100,"src":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cd\/5u7GJg_M51Y.jpg","src_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724ce\/lGtECitdDGc.jpg","src_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cc\/HkFk28TLSWI.jpg","src_xbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724cf\/sLfK2j4eZ58.jpg","src_xxbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724d0\/dG8Xb7SunJ4.jpg","src_xxxbig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c841432\/v841432491\/724d1\/JqDRas9jJ-A.jpg","width":2560,"height":1965,"text":"","created":1519305391,"post_id":10269,"access_key":"fbe37a55914e80afa1"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":20,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":3,"user_reposted":0},"online":0,"reply_count":0},{"id":10268,"from_id":-31990499,"to_id":-31990499,"date":1519293844,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Поймали предподавателя физики Ивана Егорова и попросили немедленно показать что-то летающее. 

25 февраля - занятие «Как построить самолет», 9+. Обсудим техническую сторону полета от теплового расширения до закона Бернулли, и поднимем в воздух все, что плохо лежит. 

Записаться: https:\/\/polymus.ru\/ru\/education\/science_labs\/samolet\/ #политехдетям #научныелаборатории","media":{"type":"video","owner_id":-31990499,"item_id":456239517},"attachment":{"type":"video","video":{"vid":456239517,"owner_id":-31990499,"title":"«Как построить самолет» в лаборатории Физики","duration":34,"description":"","date":1519293710,"views":759,"image":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c834\/bs5-taTENBg.jpg","image_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c834\/bs5-taTENBg.jpg","image_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c836\/t_BHtQrxwVo.jpg","access_key":"f4f7d7e4dc06777fea","repeat":1,"first_frame_320":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ab\/ut7vXD29TOI.jpg","first_frame_160":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ac\/a7ecxZMBtLQ.jpg","first_frame_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ad\/HW_b7Km1gq8.jpg","first_frame_800":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49aa\/6iWdetK5VEo.jpg"}},"attachments":[{"type":"video","video":{"vid":456239517,"owner_id":-31990499,"title":"«Как построить самолет» в лаборатории Физики","duration":34,"description":"","date":1519293710,"views":759,"image":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c834\/bs5-taTENBg.jpg","image_big":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c834\/bs5-taTENBg.jpg","image_small":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c840435\/v840435426\/5c836\/t_BHtQrxwVo.jpg","access_key":"f4f7d7e4dc06777fea","repeat":1,"first_frame_320":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ab\/ut7vXD29TOI.jpg","first_frame_160":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ac\/a7ecxZMBtLQ.jpg","first_frame_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49ad\/HW_b7Km1gq8.jpg","first_frame_800":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c824202\/v824202426\/c49aa\/6iWdetK5VEo.jpg"}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":0,"can_like":1,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":0},"online":0,"reply_count":0}]}
```

как достать из `$result` все поля "text" и вставить их в поля `<textarea> html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Можно сделать так

```
<?php
  $str = 'тут_ваша_строка';
  $b = json_decode($str, true);
  foreach($b['response'] as $value) :
?>
   <textarea><?= $value['text'] ?></textarea> 
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

$str = 'тут_ваша_строка';
Не совсем понимаю, что тут должно быть, какая строка?

Comment: Та строка, которую Вы написали в вопросе, содержимое переменной $result.

Comment: Просто подставьте в json_decode() переменную $result;

Comment: Спасибо помогло!